# Two - Step authentication, how does it work?

Tags: security, authentication, cryptography, ruby-on-rails-4

So as part of a project, I want to implement a two step authentication system (in rails)

I understand the principles of it,

=> Client: Username and password

<= Server: Generate PIN code and send it to client via SMS/email

=> Client: enter PIN

<= Server: authenticate client as normal

Now what I want to know is in a web based application such as rails, the PIN needs to be kept secret at every point, so when redirecting from the username/password part to the PIN part, I need to keep the PIN code secret while passing it over to the next part of the system (the PIN part)

Is the only decent way to do this, by temporarily storing the PIN in the database alongside a user ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not quite that.

There are two (most used) types of one-time passwords (OTPs, PINs in your terminology):

1. Time-based
2. Counter-based

Time-based ones (TOTP) generate some number based on current time (for example: number of 30-second intervals from 1970.1.1 00:00) and some shared secret. When receiving such one-time password, server generates one on its side and checks whether it's correct.

In counter-based OTPs, you have a counter and a secret key stored in database near user ID, and it is used to generate the OTP. It can be incremented based on login attempt.

Time-based tokens are usually better, as they don't require counter synchronization (time synchronization is usually easier). Best example of this is the [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2), which implements standard TOTP from [RFC6238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238).

There's one Ruby OTP library which claims compatibility with Google Authenicator, you may want to try it out: [link](https://github.com/mdp/rotp)

Can't vouch for its security and/or quality, but it looks promising.

Comment: I add the HOTP (counter based OTP) specification: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4226

Comment: If server time and client time are not synchronized means at that time what i have to do? For eg: client set his/her time for 5mins fast/slow

Comment: Well, in my opinion it's client's problem then; but Google has other opinion and implements separate time synchronization in TOTP application (ref [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2) app)